# Docsify images using AWS Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify, docsify

Trying to deploy Docsify to Amplify my images are not showing up. 
So, the official guide tells you a couple of tips (redirects and history mode) but nothing about images paths. 
I'm trying

```
logo: '../_media/logo64.png',
logo: '_media/logo64.png',
```

Both work locally but not once deployed. Any clue what could it be ?

Answer (score 1):

Found it, I'll submit a PR for docsify doc too. What you have to do in Amplify is add another redirect rule for your images (PNGs, JPGs)

Go to your apps in amplify > App settings: Rewrites and redirects
Add a new rule after the MDs one so it has this order.

[image: screenshot]